# How to create one user which have access to all the namespaces except one in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

How to create one user called `kubernetes-dashboard` and that user access my all the namespaces ns1, ns2, ns3, ns5 except ns4.

Answer (score 3):

- I have created sample namespaces ns1,ns2,ns3 & ns4.
  i want  my new user to have access to ns1,ns2,ns3 but not to ns4

```
kubectl get ns
NAME              STATUS   AGE
calico-system     Active   21h
default           Active   21h
kube-node-lease   Active   21h
kube-public       Active   21h
kube-system       Active   21h
ns1               Active   36m
ns2               Active   36m
ns3               Active   36m
ns4               Active   36m
tigera-operator   Active   21h
```

1. Create a [sample service account](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/creating-sample-user.md#creating-a-service-account) named "kubernetes-dashboard" in default namespace:

```
[root@project1kubemaster ~]# kubectl create serviceaccount kubernetes-dashboard
serviceaccount/kubernetes-dashboard created
```

2. Create [ClusterRole](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#clusterrole-example) named "kubernetes-dashboard-role"

```
[root@project1kubemaster ~]# kubectl create clusterrole kubernetes-dashboard-role --verb=* --resource=*
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard-role created
```

3. Create separate [RoleBinding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-example) in each namespaces of our interest (ns1,ns2,n3) but not on ns4:

```
[root@project1kubemaster ~]# kubectl create rolebinding kubernetes-dashboard-rolebinding-ns1 --clusterrole=kubernetes-dashboard-role --namespace=ns1 --serviceaccount=default:kubernetes-dashboard
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard-rolebinding-ns1 created

[root@project1kubemaster ~]# kubectl create rolebinding kubernetes-dashboard-rolebinding-ns2 --clusterrole=kubernetes-dashboard-role --namespace=ns2 --serviceaccount=default:kubernetes-dashboard
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard-rolebinding-ns2 created

[root@project1kubemaster ~]# kubectl create rolebinding kubernetes-dashboard-rolebinding-ns3 --clusterrole=kubernetes-dashboard-role --namespace=ns3 --serviceaccount=default:kubernetes-dashboard
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard-rolebinding-ns3 created
```

4. Testing :

```
[root@project1kubemaster ~]# kubectl auth can-i get pods -n ns1 --as  system:serviceaccount:default:kubernetes-dashboard
yes
[root@project1kubemaster ~]# kubectl auth can-i get pods -n ns2 --as  system:serviceaccount:default:kubernetes-dashboard
yes
[root@project1kubemaster ~]# kubectl auth can-i get pods -n ns3 --as  system:serviceaccount:default:kubernetes-dashboard
yes
[root@project1kubemaster ~]# kubectl auth can-i get pods -n ns4 --as  system:serviceaccount:default:kubernetes-dashboard
no
```

Comment: Thanks for info, can we run the k8s-dashboard in the same way, as I need to exclude one namespace which is looking difficult to do. this is the file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.4/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml, point out if you have any clue

Comment: getting error:- as per above solution , "error: you must specify two or three arguments: verb, resource, and optional resourceName"

Comment: @GauravAgnihotri which command is giving the error "error: you must specify two or three arguments: verb, resource, and optional resourceName" ?

Comment: this one:- kubectl auth can-i get pods -n ns1 --as  system:serviceaccount:default:kubernetes-dashboard

Comment: Thats weird , it is woking fine for me ``` [root@project1kubemaster ~]# kubectl auth can-i get pods -n ns1 --as system:serviceaccount:default:kubernetes-dashboard
no
```

Comment: what are the changes we need to add if we use this file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.4/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml